# Java: How to Read numbers from a file using FileChannel

Tags: java

I have a large text file having thousands of numbers in it that are separated by spaces. I want to read each number using Java FileChannel.

I was able to read the file using the first method mentioned here: http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/05/01/3-ways-to-read-files-using-java-nio/ but i am not sure how i would read each number of two, three and four digits.

My Code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    try
    {
        String file_name="abc.txt";
        RandomAccessFile input_file = new RandomAccessFile(file_name,"r");
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file_name);
        FileChannel ch = in.getChannel();
        FileChannel inChannel = input_file.getChannel();
        long file_size = inChannel.size();
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate((int) file_size);

        Charset cs = Charset.forName("ASCII");
        // inChannel.read(buffer);

        int rd;
        while ( (rd = ch.read( buffer )) != -1 ) 
        {
            buffer.rewind();
            System.out.println("String read: ");
            CharBuffer chbuf = cs.decode(buffer);

            for ( int i = 0; i < chbuf.length(); i++ ) 
            {

               System.out.print(chbuf.get());
            }
            buffer.clear();
            inChannel.close();
            input_file.close();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException exc){}
```

}
}

Comment: Do you mean the first method that uses nio? I can' even get that working. I get a java.nio.BufferUnderflowException.

Comment: I mean 

1) Read a small file in buffer of file size

Its working perfectly ...

Comment: Did you get a java.nio.BufferUnderflowException at any point? What does the file you read look like in this case? Did you need to modify the code at all?

Comment: Oh, sorry i forgot to mention that i made few changes and then it started working but any ways, the file is being read now. The problem is that i want to read each number separately.

Comment: Can you post your modified code? You could try using int length = buffer.getInt();
System.out.println("Size : " + length);

Comment: Added, Please check at the description.

Comment: I've just edited the code I posted in my answer to isolate each integer, as I realised that the previous code only isolated the characters. Now it converts them into Integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your code to isolate each number separately (it didn't need much modification):

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ReadFile {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try
        {   
            String s; 
            Integer I;
            String file_name="C:/Users/User/test.txt";
            RandomAccessFile input_file = new RandomAccessFile(file_name,"r");
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file_name);
            FileChannel ch = in.getChannel();
            FileChannel inChannel = input_file.getChannel();
            long file_size = inChannel.size();
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate((int) file_size);

            Charset cs = Charset.forName("ASCII");
            ArrayList<Character> character = new ArrayList<Character>();
            // inChannel.read(buffer);

            int rd;
            while ( (rd = ch.read( buffer )) != -1 ) 
            {
                buffer.rewind();

                CharBuffer chbuf = cs.decode(buffer);

                System.out.println("ASCII values read: ");

                System.out.println();

                     for ( int i = 0; i < chbuf.length(); i++ ) 
                    {

                        int j = chbuf.get();

                        character.add((char)j);

                        System.out.println("j("+i+"): "+j+" ");

                    }

                     System.out.println();

                     System.out.println("Chars they represent: ");

                     System.out.println();

                     for ( int i = 0; i < character.size(); i++ ) 
                        {

                        System.out.println("character("+i+"): "+character.get(i)+" ");
                        System.out.println();
                        s = character.get(i).toString();
                        if(!(s.equals(" ")||s.equals("\r")))
                            {
                            System.out.println("s("+i+"): "+s+" ");
                            System.out.println();
                            System.out.println("s("+i+").length(): "+s.length()+" ");
                            System.out.println();
                            I = new Integer(s);
                            System.out.println("I("+i+"): "+I+" ");
                            System.out.println();
                            }
                        }

                buffer.clear();
                inChannel.close();
                input_file.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException exc){}
    }
}
```